# Edit Query is not working in CMS system

Tags: php

```
<form action="categories.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_title"> Edit Category </label>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
                $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = $cat_id ";
                $select_cat_gories = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                if (!$select_cat_gories) {

                    die("query failed".mysqli_error($connection));
                }
                while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_cat_gories)) {
                    $id = $rows['cat_id'];
                    $title = $rows['cat_title'];


                    ?>

                    <input value="<?php if(isset($title)){ echo $title;} ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title">
                    <?php
                }
            } ?>

            <?php

            if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {

                $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];

                if (isset($_POST['upddate'])) {
                    $title = $_POST['cat_title'];
                    $query = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '{$title}' WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
                    $update_query = mysqli_connect($connection, $query);

                    if (!$update_query) {

                        die("query Failed".mysqli_error($connection));
                    }
                }
            }

        ?>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="upddate" value="Update_category">
    </div>
</form>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>  Id</th>
                <th> Category title </th>
                <th> Delete </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
                $select_cat_gories = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_cat_gories)){
                    $id = $rows['cat_id'];
                    $title = $rows['cat_title'];
                    echo "
                    <tr>
                        ";
                        echo "
                        <td>{$id}</td>";
                        echo "
                        <td>{$title}</td>";
                        echo "
                        <td><a href='categories.php?delete={$id}'> delete </a> </td>";
                        echo "
                        <td><a href='categories.php?edit={$id}'> Edit </a></td>";
                        echo "
                    </tr>";
                }
            ?>
```

I have been trying to edit contents in Table, I have created a table where I have shown a add category, and an update category these both are text fields there in webpage, on the same page there is table with columns id, title, edit and delete, all others things are working fine except the edit category when I click on edit link to edit any category it does shows it in input field but not editing it when I click on update category.

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating value request will be in post so the condition

```
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
```

never makes true. You have to store id into hidden field while editing and then update value. Also there is an error in your update query

change your code as following

```
<form action="categories.php" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="cat_title"> Edit Category </label>
                                    <?php
                                        if(isset($_GET['edit']))
                                        {
                                                $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = $cat_id ";
                                                $select_cat_gories = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                                                if(!$select_cat_gories){

                                                    die ("query failed". mysqli_error($connection));
                                                }
                                                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_cat_gories))
                                                {
                                                    $id = $rows['cat_id'];
                                                    $title = $rows['cat_title'];


                                                ?>

                                    <input value="<?php if(isset($title)){ echo $title;} ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title"> 
                                    <input value="<?php echo $id; ?>" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="cat_id"> 
                                    <?php }} ?>

                                    <?php





                                        if(isset($_POST['upddate']))
                                        {
                                            $title = $_POST['cat_title'];
                                            $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
                                            $query = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '{$title}' WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
                                            $update_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

                                            if(!$update_query)
                                                {

                                                    die("query Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
                                                }
                                        }

                                    ?>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="upddate" value="Update_category">
                                </div>
                            </form>   
                          </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>  Id</th>
                                        <th> Category title </th>
                                        <th> Delete </th>    
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                             $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
                                                $select_cat_gories = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                                            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_cat_gories))
                                            {
                                                $id = $rows['cat_id'];
                                                $title = $rows['cat_title'];
                                                echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td>{$id}</td>";
                                                echo "<td>{$title}</td>";
                                                echo "<td><a href='categories.php?delete={$id}'> delete </a> </td>";
                                                echo "<td><a href='categories.php?edit={$id}'> Edit </a></td>";
                                                echo "</tr>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
```

Comment: Just i have to make it hidden?

Comment: yes and remove condition `if(isset($_GET['edit']))` before `if(isset($_POST['upddate']))`

Comment: Sir if i remove edit it would call it un defined cat id in query and type hidden will make it hidden then how i will edit any Category, i have a snapshot of the table would you like to see then examine

Comment: You have two times this condition `if(isset($_GET['edit']))`. I told remove this only from second time. OR simply copy paste my answer's code and then try